# Deal with console input (newline)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For a console menu in Java, I sometimes want to read integers and some strings. I have these two functions:

To get a String:

```
public String enterString(String question) {
    System.out.println(question);
    return scanner.nextLine();
}
```

To get an int (for a switch statement later):

```
public int choose(int b, String question) {
    Boolean chosen = false;     
    while(!chosen) {
        chosen = true;
        System.out.println(question);
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();

        if(choice >= 0 && choice <= b) {
            return choice;
        }
        else {
            chosen = false;
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice.");
        }
    }
    return 0; //the compiler complains otherwise
}
```

However, if I use `enterString()` first and then `choose()` and then `enterString()`, it seems to use the newline from choose. Entering `scanner.nextLine()` at various places (start and end of each function) always caused problems.

How can I make any combination of the two work?

Comment: You can create a parser to check if your input is a string or an integer based on if it contains only numbers or also letters

Comment: for a start, in `choose()` it should be `boolean` not `Boolean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nextInt()` is not going to consume the EOL. So, either scan for `Int` as

```
 int choice = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

or, consume the extra new line

```
 int choice = scanner.nextInt();
 scanner.nextLine(); // Skip
```

Comment: The second option seems to work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

scanner.nextInt() does not consume the line-end.
You could wrap the nextLine in a while loop and ask for input again if the line is empty.